# Define C++ conversion operator only if template arg is not const

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-conversion, template-meta-programming

I'm writing custom conversion operator from `CContainer<CLASS>` to `CContainer<const CLASS>`. The code looks like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
class CContainer
{
public:
    operator CContainer<const T>() const { /* here goes the code */ }
};
```

and ***technicaly*** it works well, but some compilers print warnings like `operator CContainer<const T>() const will never be used` each time when there is an explicit instantiation with constant template argument, like `CContainer<const float> constFloatContainer;`.

Is there a way to avoid this warning, and define operators like this only when `T` is not `const` in **C++11**?

Comment: Could you make a [mre]? Where do you get these warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution is use SFINAE to enable the operator only when `T` is different from `T const`.

For example (caution: code not tested)

```
template <typename U = T,
   typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<U, T const>::value, int>::type = 0>
operator CContainer<U const>() const
 { /* here goes the code */ }
```

or, as suggested by Remy Lebeau (thanks) you can use `std::is_const`

```
template <typename U = T,
   typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_const<U>::value, int>::type = 0>
operator CContainer<U const>() const
 { /* here goes the code */ }
```

Comment: What about using `!std::is_const<T>::value` instead of using `false == std::is_same<U, T const>::value`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau what about using `not std::is_const_v<T>`?

Comment: Oh, I realized that it didn't exist back in C++11. Thank god they added that.

Comment: @JanSchultke - Exactly (but I maintain the "For"; thanks).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - D'Oh! I had forgotten the existence of `std::is_const`. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why we need to use `false ==` instead of `!`?

Comment: @JanSchultke - There is a particular reason because I use `false ==` instead of `!`: I don't see very well, so there is the risk that, maintaining the code, I don't see the `!` (that is very little), so I prefer `false ==` that great and clear. For this reason (there are other programmer with bad eyes) I suggest to avoid `!` in this context.

Comment: @max66 I don't ever use `!`, I use `not`. All logical operators can be used via keyword too, like `&&` = `and` and `^` = `xor`. If you have bad eyesight, those might be helpful.

Comment: @JanSchultke - You're right, `not` is a good solution. But I have another problem: I'm old. I've discovered the alternative representation of operators after 20 years of C/C++ programming. I'm so used to the classical representation that I don't think to the alternative. But you're right: it's a good solution.

Comment: `not` is the one alternative I like the most. I have bad eyesight and it's really easy to miss `!` for me nowadays. For some reason the others, like `^`, doesn't cause me problems.

Comment: That looks like a good answer to a question that seemingly should have been stated differently (XY problem statement here). This should be achieved by a converting constructor, instead of by a conversion function. Then the code would dramatically simplify.